# how to extract variable from file.txt unix

Tags: bash, shell

How to extract "oid" from a file with the following structure using shell scripting?

```
file name :variable
file body:
"title":"script1"
"oid":"jjjnerfjeffrefef6"
"user":"xxxx"
```

I would like to only extract the oid value (jjjnerfjeffrefef6).

Comment: Please use [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to help us understand what the contents of the file look like.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$s"
"title":"script1" "oid":"jjjnerfjeffrefef6" "user":"xxxx"
```

You can use `sed` with a regex:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -ne 's/^.*"oid":"\([^"]*\).*$/\1/p' 
jjjnerfjeffrefef6
```

Which would also work for a file:

```
$ sed -ne 's/^.*"oid":"\([^"]*\).*$/\1/p' file.txt
```

Comment: If it is useful to you, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)